# How are people with same reputation ranked?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

In the all time reputation leagues I have the same reputation as a few others and I'm ranked somewhere within them.

[image: Ranking of several people with the same reputation]

I'd assume the ranking would be based on the number of badges in that case. E.g. in my case 2 gold, 16 silver and 37 bronze badges. This makes a total of 55 badges.
Using weighted numbers like e.g. gold counts three times, silver two times and bronze one time, this would result in 2 · 3 + 16 · 2 + 37 · 1 = 75.
Though the numbers are lower than the ones of Marco W. (301 total, 451 weighted), which is ranked after me and higher than the ones of Cagatay Civici (24 total, 33 weighted), which is ranked higher than me.
So the rank obviously does not depend on the number of badges.

Also the time being a member doesn't seem to have any influence on the ranking, as I am member for a longer timespan than the user Cactus, which is ranked higher than me, but shorter than Marco W., which is ranked lower than me.

Therefore I wonder, what criterias are used for the ranking in case the reputation of multiple users is equal?

Comment: Are you working for Stack Exchange Inc. or how do you know that SE uses the .NET Framework and its [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method?

Comment: Hans knows SE uses .NET [because they've told everyone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/179419); as for Sort(), I assume this is an educated guess.

Answer (score 6):

From what I've observed, it's first person wins.  It makes *perfect* sense from a ranking standpoint, and it's also what I've observed anecdotally from events such as Winter Bash.

If you're the first person to some arbitrary reputation value, then your name would appear first in the list.  Whomever else reached that arbitrary reputation value after you would be placed in the list after your entry.

Comment: Probably because the rows are kept in update order when not explicitly ordered. So if your last reputation change was recorded earlier than someone else, you'll be listed first. E.g. there is no real set order and it is implementation dependent based on the database used.

Answer (score 3):

I just realized that this question was already asked on Meta Stack Exchange as [SO reputation league rankings for same score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139953/252674).

The answer of [Emmet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/144066/emmett) was:

> The tie-breaking behavior is currently *undefined*. I don't think we
> ever gave it much thought, so this is subject to change in the future.

Stack Exchange and all its sub-sites [are obviously based on ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) and using its [sorting functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is unstable in case of two equal entries.

To improve the current behavior I added [my suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248424/252674) to the [request for allowing ties in the leagues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225003/252674).